# How to count number of clicks on an Image in HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Written the following code to get the required result:

html file:

```
<div class="container">
    <img id="myImg" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="cat.jpg" alt="cat img">
</div>
```

JS File:

```
$(function() {
    let i = 0;
    $('#myImg').click(function() {
        $(this).html(i++);
    });
});
```

But, the console show error as follows:

```
 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined
at script.js:1
```

Could you please help me to resolve this problem and explain to me why does this happen. And how can I know the number of click increment or not?

[Click here](https://codepen.io/sofianayak55/pen/jvgbga) for codepen link of my work.

Comment: you need to link jquery file before your script.js file

Comment: You need to include jquery library on your page. Add `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>` to your `<head>`

Comment: Try to google your error before asking for solution here.  Put some efforts into your problem, solving them, before asking. This is common error and there would be so many google answers to this.

Comment: 1. you have not added the resource (jquery) file in your snippet.

Comment: Thank you so much, everyone. My problem resolved now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uncomment your link to jquery file i.e `<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>` and include your script.js after jQuery file. You are getting error because your `<script src="script.js"></script>` is before jquery. All you JavaScript which use jQuery must be after your jQuery file.

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Click Cat | Sofia </title>
  </head>
  <body>

    
    <div class="container">
    <img id="myImg" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="http://www.petsworld.in/blog/wp-content/uploads/2014/09/adorable-cat.jpg" alt="cat img">
    </div>

 
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-KJ3o2DKtIkvYIK3UENzmM7KCkRr/rE9/Qpg6aAZGJwFDMVNA/GpGFF93hXpG5KkN" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
       <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script>
       $(function(){
    let i=0;
     $('#myImg').click(function(){
        $(this).html(i++);
        console.log(i);
       });
     });
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to use jQuery in your javascript code, but you may not have properly included the jquery script file in your HTML.

You can load it in the head of your document from a cdn like this:

```
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
```

After the jQuery script is included, you may want to modify your HTML to have an element that will hold the count (not the img element):

```
<div class="container">
    <span id="click-counter">0</span>
    <img id="myImg" class="img-fluid img-thumbnail" src="cat.jpg" alt="cat img">
</div>
```

Then adjust your js code:

```
$(function() {
    let i = 0;
    $('#myImg').click(function() {
        i++;
        $('#click-counter').text(i);
    });
});
```

Here is a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/2zxmhub4/1/

Comment: ya..that error is removed now. but the click() not work..means I can't able to know the number of clicks increment or not.

Comment: I edited my answer.  It should show an html element with the count.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var i = 1;
    $('#myImg').click(function(){
        alert(i++); // here you can use html or whatever you want.
    });
});
```

remove the alert and use whatever you want